# How to use the DEBUG constant like a variable

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

Maybe a duplicate - I just can't figure out what to google...

In C#, is it possible to use the DEBUG constant like a variable such as

```
Boolean debugging = DEBUG;
```

I'd like to avoid this:

```
#if DEBUG
    Boolean debugging = true;
#else
    Boolean debugging = false;
#endif
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the purpose? `DEBUG` should just be used during compile time. At runtime, it's usually more important to consider e.g. whether a debugger is attached, whether the JIT is generating optimized code, etc, and there are specific runtime mechanisms for discovering that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. The typical way would be the way you specifically didn't want to do. However, if you're hard set on not using `#if`, you can use [ConditionalAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) to do something similar. For instance:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {               
        Boolean debug = false;
        CheckForDebug(ref debug);

        Console.WriteLine("debug = " + debug);
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void CheckForDebug(ref Boolean debug)
    {
        debug = true;
    }
}
```

This might be of use to you outside of the specific question you asked here. `ConditionalAttribute` is useful for making sure a method that returns void is only run when `DEBUG` (or any arbitrary preprocessor symbol) is defined.

Example: http://rextester.com/JXHE87904

Answer (score 1):

The typical way is to use it like this:

```
#if DEBUG
   Boolean debugging = true;
#else
   Boolean debugging = false;
#endif
```

Cheers!